# Как организовать вывод меню и параметров на сайте в зависимости от произведен ли вход на сайт?

Tags: python, html, веб-программирование, flask

Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше сделать **меню** на сайте? Допустим у меня есть 4 страницы на сайте 1)главная, 2)контакты, 3)товары, 4)производители. 1,2,3 стр доступны всем, а 4-только авторизованным пользователям? И **как** на странице товары часть параметров по товару доступно только для авторизованных пользователей. Пишу проект на python, использую flask. Да, я могу через сессию параметр передать, или полностью список на сервере сформировать, но может есть какой то более правильный метод, что бы не делать костыли?